# Unity изменение высоты объекта через функцию Синуса

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит такая задача, чтобы изменять высоту куба периодически через фун Mathf.Sin(timer), но я подозреваю, что сделал реализацию неправильно, так как не могу понять, как корректно обновить счетчик, чтобы его значение не улетало в космос.

```
float timer = 0;
Vector3 pos;  

void Start () {
  pos = transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
  timer = timer + 1 * Time.deltaTime;
  pos.y += Mathf.Sin(timer) * Time.deltaTime;
  transform.position = pos;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```cs
float timer = 0;
Vector3 pos;
float y;  

void Start () {
  pos = transform.position;
  y = pos.y;
}

void Update()
{
  timer += Time.deltaTime;
  if (timer > 2.0f * Mathf.PI)
      timer -= 2.0f * Mathf.PI;
  pos.y = y + Mathf.Sin(timer) * 10;
  transform.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос был конкретно не в этом, но благодарю.

Comment: А в чем был вопрос? На мой взгляд предложенный код решает проблему, описанную вами. Переменная присваивается, а не увеличивается?

Comment: @HerrDonULt обновил ответ.

Comment: Это да, но я бы хотел спросить начет счетчика, если он увеличится до немыслемых масштабов, то все норм, так можно оставлять, иили надо был счетчик все таи обновлять?

Comment: @HerrDonULt если вам помог ответ, отметьте его принятым. Вообще большое число с плавающей точкой = низкая точность. Поэтому да, синус или косинус высчитывается от радиан, и при превышении значения 2 Пи его сбрасывать, то есть вычитать 2 Пи. Тригонометрия здесь вам отвечает на все вопросы. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, помог, только исправьте то, что выдает ошибку, потому как нельзя к transform.y присваивать. Считает как переменную.

Answer (score 0):

```
[SerializeField] private float _offsetPosition = 10f; // размах
[SerializeField] private float _cycleTime = 2f; // время одного цикла
private Transform _transform;
private Vector3 _anchorPosition;
private float _timer;

private void Awake () {
    _transform = transform;
    _anchorPosition = _transform.position;
}

private void Update () {
    _timer += Time.deltaTime*Mathf.PI*2f/_cycleTime;
    _timer %= Mathf.PI*2f; // остаток от деления на 2 Pi
    float SinY = Mathf.Sin(_timer)*_offsetPosition;
    _transform.position = _anchorPosition+new Vector3(0, SinY, 0);
}
```